# Possible to add tasks to a chord in a loop?

Tags: python, celery

Most of the chord examples I have found are along this line:

```
res = chord([add.s(2, 2), add.s(4, 4)])(sum_task.s())
```

or

```
chord(add.subtask((i, i))
...     for i in xrange(100))(tsum.subtask()).get()
```

I currently have a piece of code that is firing off tasks:

```
for node in self.simulationRecord.fields['departureNodes']:
    passengers = int(outgoing_seat_counts.get(node, 0)) 
    # send the job to the queue
    res = tasks.my_task.delay(passengers, start_date, end_date)
    task_ids.append(res.id)
```

that I would like to convert to using chords, but I can't quite figure out how to convert my current structure to use chords based on the examples I have seen.  How would I go about adding each call to `my_task` with parameters to a chord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my code to what I have below to use chords.  Basically I am building the argument list in the loop and then creating the chord using that:

```
arg_list = []
for node in self.simulationRecord.fields['departureNodes']:
    passengers = int(outgoing_seat_counts.get(node, 0)) 
    arg_list.append({'passengers': passengers})
res = chord(tasks.my_task.s(i['passengers'],start_date,end_date) for i in arg_list)(tasks.callback.s())
task_ids = [task.id for task in res.parent.results]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `chord` from a list of tasks and a call back. For example, if you have an add function, then you can call chord like this

```
tasks = []

for i in range(10):
    tasks.append(add.s(i, i))

callback = add.si(100, 100)

chord_result = group(tasks)(callback)
```